# Field and dimension of the set of all differential forms (as a vectorspace)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Intrinsic_definitions) says

> The set of all differential $k$-forms on a manifold $M$ is a vector space, often denoted $\Omega^k(M)$.

Over which field is this vector space defined?

Let $\dim(M)=:n$. What is the dimension of the vector space $\Omega^k(M)$?

Comment: It's uncountably infinite. It's the space of sections of a *vector bundle* whose fibers are dimension n choose k.

Comment: @MikeMiller And over which filed is this space defined? I first guessed $C^\infty$ but this is not a field, I think.

Comment: Is not always vector space, is a module over the ring of smooth functions  $C^\infty(M)$

Comment: Look at chapter 8 of Jeffrey Lee's "Manifolds and differential geometry" for more depth. It's an awesome book (do not mistake with the other Lee author).

Comment: @basweber: The obvious field is $\Bbb R$. This is, for instance, what the exterior derivative is linear over. You can consider it as a $C^\infty(M)$-module, which if I am remembering my commutative algebra right, has a well-defined rank, which is n choose k. But the exterior derivative is not linear over $C^\infty(M)$, of course; instead it satisfies the Leibniz rule $d(f\omega) = df \wedge \omega \pm f \wedge d\omega$ (the $\pm$ depending on $k$).